# Why cant I install 3rd party programs from Ubuntu Software center?

Tags: system-installation

For example if I try downloading skype. It brings it up in the software center , I click install and nothing happens! Happens with every 3rd party program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some 3rd party programs may need some other packages to be installed. The Software Center is not really good to install this type of software.

It is much better to install using the `dpkg -i` terminal command. If there are dependency errors, follow it by the

```
sudo apt install -f
```

command. It will install required dependencies.

You will also see any other problems if any.

Another option is to use `gdebi` graphical application.

Comment: Thanks, For a second I thought my installer had glitched or something.